# Accessing modal dialog variable after calling dispose method

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, modal-dialog, dispose

Situation: a main form calls a modal jDialog with textboxes in which parameters are filled in by the user to create or modify an instance of a certain class, call it ClassA.

When the dialog needs to modify an existing instance, it is passed in the constructor as a parameter. Otherwise the jDialog will create a new instance of ClassA.

Problem: the mainform needs to access that new instance, and I think it is unclean code to pass the entire main form as a parameter, and let the dialog push the new instance into it by a method call, because that way a perfectly re-usable stand-alone dialog becomes only usable with one single main form that needs a certain classname and method to receive the new instance.

It is much more logical to make the main form get the new instance from the jdialog after the OK button is clicked, by calling a getClassAInstance() method (which could be called also when an existing instance was being modified). The method is called after the "setVisible(true)" method on a new instance of the jdialog in question. The dialog appears, the thread of the main form will sleep until the dialog is closed (because it is modal). The OK button calls the dispose() method of the jDialog, then the very next statement is the getClassAInstance() call on the jDialog by the mainform.

Here's the same thing in code..

```
ClassAInstanceMakerDialog imd = new ClassAInstanceMakerDialog(this, true);
imd.setVisible(true);
//imd.dispose(); after OK button click
System.out.println(imd.getClassAInstance()); //return a new ClassA instance

//output: whatever ClassA.toString() should return, works fine
```

Question: I've tried it and it seems to work perfectly fine. But, is it a good code? Is there any danger of the getClassAInstance() method returning "null", because the garbage collector collected the ClassA instance after the jDialog was disposed and before the main form could complete the call?

Please excuse me if I didn't make myself clear, I'm not a native English speaker. If you would rather see some code, let me know...

Comment: Your English is fine and your question well constructed, 1+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perfectly legal to access the member variable of your dialog instance that holds the ClassA instance, the dialog instance will not be garbage collected until it goes out of scope, not just because you called dispose on it.

I'd give slight preference to a solution where you define an event handler interface with a signature of

someThingHappened(ClassA toThisObject), make your mainform or anything that might be interested that ClassA thing implement that interface make it possible to add listeners to the dialog before making it visible.

That way, you would loosen the coupling between the dialog and the main form a little.

Comment: Indeed that is a good idea, that will also let me clean up the code in case the dialog is disposed in any other way than clicking the OK button, in which case the getClassAInstance() method will always return null if it needed to create a new ClassA instance.

Comment: +1 You can `firePropertyChange()` from, add an `Observable` delegate to, the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `dispose()` sets the JDialog up for garbage collection, but instead just releases resources. The dialog is still re-usable as per the [Window API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) (since JDialog inherits this method from Window):

> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.
>
> The Window and its subcomponents can be made displayable again by rebuilding the native resources with a subsequent call to pack or show. The states of the recreated Window and its subcomponents will be identical to the states of these objects at the point where the Window was disposed (not accounting for additional modifications between those actions).
>
> Note: When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate. See AWT Threading Issues for more information.

As long as there are valid *reachable* references to the JDialog object still present, it will not be garbage collected. I think that the cost of disposing the dialog is that your code will need to spend a (very) little bit of time to re-create the resources.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I would vote up but I don't have enough reputation yet :)

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow.com!

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly reasonable and appropriate to have an `IDisposable` include properties or methods which may be used after `Dispose` is called to return information about things which happened before `Dispose` was called.  Rather than blindly enforcing a rule that any and all methods of a disposed object should throw an `ObjectDisposedException`, one should instead consider which methods and properties do or do not make sense on disposed objects.  Attempting to access a disposed object should throw `ObjectDisposedException` *in preference to re-acquiring released resources or letting escape some other exception which occurs as a consequence of the disposal*.  If the method or property access can succeed without any of the released resources, it should often be allowed to do so.